# My WiFi speed stuck at 1Mb/s

Tags: wireless, 18.04, kubuntu, download-speed

so I read multiple threads about this problem and my **rate** is limited to 1Mb/s (or that is what `iwconfig` tells me.)
Here is my output of `iwconfig`:

```
    lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx98ded00e2a41  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Niko PC"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: 64:66:B3:C3:E0:90   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5685   Missed beacon:0

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

I am using TL-WN822N v4 and I am connected to my home network.
I tried running `sudo iwconfig wlx98ded00e2a41 rate 54M` whhich outputs:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Bit Rate" (8B20) :
SET failed on device wlx98ded00e2a41 ; Operation not supported.
```

Then I tried with `wlan0` which is not even listed and it just said, device not found. Thanks guys.

I have tried installing my drivers - did not help (not sure if done correctly).

E:// Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
3: phy3: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Edited and added the output.

Comment: Please guys I need this.

Comment: You can use search and find a solution for this USB adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing rtl8192 drivers solved this issue.